# php script redirecting code problem

Tags: php, redirect

i'm using a php script for redirection after detecting the search word to my websiter from the search engines .

and my redirection code is working fine

but for some keywods i wat to stay in the same page. for that lines of code i'm getting a warning message in that pages.

```
Warning:  headers already sent 
          (output started at /home/friendsj/public_html/index.php:2) in
          /home/friendsj/public_html/index.php on line 20
```

below is the code i used in that pages

```
$ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if(strstr($ref,"test")){ 
  $url="http://www.howtomark.com/robgoyette.html";
}
else if(strstr($ref,"mu+word+gmail")){
    $url="http://www.howtomark.com/marketbetter.html";
}
else{
  if(strstr($ref,"how+to+market+better")){
  }    
}

if($url !=""){
  header("Location:$url");
}
```

Comment: You can use the '0101010' button to format code. Otherwise, it's not readable.

Comment: Also Check U r not Left with any blank space at the end of file after "?>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirections are accomplished by setting an HTTP header, as the use of the `header()` function suggests. That means that you can only redirect *before* you start the document output. Whatever you start printing on line 2, do it later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

remove any output started at the 2nd line at index.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Header function you are not allowed to output something before that function is called.

In you case you wrote in line 2 on index.php something to output.

A bad workaround is to use the output cache functions ob_start.
but this is not a real solution.

Comment: Why are output cache functions not a real solution?

Comment: @Manos: because the better is to cure disease, and not just hide symptoms

Comment: Dr. zerkms is in Wrong Community, We need a coder to explain :)

Comment: @zerkms The "disease" is unavoidable in larger applications, especially OO frameworks, where you have no idea what/when controllers might try to do. Using output buffering is a perfectly acceptable strategy. In fact it's often unavoidable.

Comment: @Manos Dilaverakis: 1. he has 10 lines script. 2. OO frameworks always use ideology of chain of responsibility/intercept filters/request-response - so we NEVER EVER could do direct echo, because we have "response" object to interact to user. the ob_* is perfectly ugly and lame strategy

Comment: @Parth: i speak english weakly and i might say what i think wrongly but don't you agree with me? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms When I talk about output buffering in OO frameworks I am referring to the framework itself (the core), not the code written by the framework adopters.

Comment: the last step within a framework is rendering. sure sometimes they are also using ob_cache functions. but they never use ob_cache to avoid problems with header()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php ob_start();
$ref='some text goes here';

if(strstr($ref,"test")){ 
  $url="http://www.howtomark.com/robgoyette.html";
}
else if(strstr($ref,"mu+word+gmail")){
    $url="http://www.howtomark.com/marketbetter.html";
}
else{
  if(strstr($ref,"how+to+market+better")){
  }    
}

if(isset($url) && !empty($url)) {
  header("location:$url");
}
ob_flush();
?>
```